# node access restrict ( Drupal 6 )

Tags: users

We have around 150 nodes of type "X". We want to show only 20 nodes out of that for all the users ( including anonymous ) except users having role "Y". For users with role "Y" will be able to see all the 150 nodes. How can I achieve this?.

Answer (score 0):

There are two module to control node access by user type. [Node_Access_1](http://drupal.org/project/node_access) & [Node_Access_2](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess). Use which ever suits you. You will have to set the permission by editing each node, as I have implemented one from it in D7. I have never tried for VBO with it, so can't answer about multiple change..